# Creating Certificate and KeyValue

Tags: c#, certificate

I'm quite new to the whole certificate-thing so I hope you can help me out.

I need to create a self-signed X509Certificate2 certificate and a get the dependent KeyValue for my project. What is the best way to create those files?

I already tried makecert.exe but I haven't figured out how to get/set the KeyValue.

The content of the files is not important since they are for test purposes only.